# Como convertir un booleando a string en un Store procedure SQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure, sql-server-2008-r2

Tengo un el siguiente procedure (select) que me regresa algunos datos:

```
 SELECT id_accion, accion_tomada, CAST(fec_inicio AS VARCHAR) AS fecha_ini, 
 CAST(fec_fin AS VARCHAR) AS fecha_fin, estatus 
 FROM detalles WHERE id_downtime = @id_dt
```

El campo estatus es de tipo bit me regresa un 0 o un 1, quiero adecuar el select para cuando me regrese un 0 = 'abierto' y el 1 = 'cerrado'.
Alguna idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar CASE asi:

```
SELECT id_accion, accion_tomada, CAST(fec_inicio AS VARCHAR) AS fecha_ini, 
CAST(fec_fin AS VARCHAR) AS fecha_fin, 
CASE estatus 
  WHEN 0 THEN 'abierto'
  WHEN 1 THEN 'cerrado'
END AS status
FROM detalles WHERE id_downtime = @id_dt
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda!